# Чем отличается "сырой" от "мокрый"?

Tags: значения

Кажется, что это совершенно взаимозаменяемые слова. Однако, очевидно, они имеют разные корни и, видимо, разные оттенки значений. Может быть, они передают разную степень влажности предмета? Или о вещи говорят "мокрая", если её поверхность влажная, тогда как если сказать о ней "сырая", это значило бы, что она пропитана влагой насквозь? Если да, то в какую категорию вписать слово "влажный"?

Comment: No, they are not always interchangeable. For example, 'сырое мясо' or 'сырая вода' are not interchangeable with 'мокрое мясо/вода' :)

Comment: @Serg But what is `сырая вода`?

Comment: @Prizoff - not boiled; like `сырое мясо` = not cooked

Comment: 'Сырая вода' means 'not boiled', got from open water, and its drinking can cause illness.
'Сырое мясо' also means 'not prepared'

Comment: 'сырое мясо' - 'raw meat'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main difference between these words, as has been mentioned in other answers is the level/amount of moisture in the object as well as whether the moisture is *outside on the object* or *inside as part of the object*.

- *Сырой* means that the object contains moisture as part of it (either originally or by modifications) and is also used to reflect a small amount of moisture. For example, *сырой пол*, *сырой воздух*, and even *сырой пирог* - in the latter example, although used as *undercooked*, the origin of the meaning is the same: contains too much moisture to be ready, cooking more will get rid of it. The best English translation of it would be *damp* (except for the *undercooked* meaning).
- *Мокрый* means that the object is covered with moisture from the outside, but not necessarily wet through-and-through inside (although it can be). For example, *мокрая курица*, *мокрый пол*.  The obvious translation into English is *wet*.
- *Влажный* is a smaller-scale version of *мокрый*.  For example, *влажное полотенце*, *влажные руки*. I'd say that the English equivalent is *moist*.  Here the idea is that the moisture coming from the outside, not necessarily (but possibly) getting inside as well, yet there isn't enough moisture to make the object *wet* (*мокрым*).

Overall, while there may be rare cases where these words can be interchangeable, usually they are not, as their meanings differ.

Comment: Sorry for being a smart ass here but as long as the question is in Russian so should be the answer.

Comment: All above answers are quite good. Just to add: "crude oil" in Russian is "сырая нефть"

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле разница интуитивна в каждой конкретной ситуации. Сочетания слов нужно запоминать. В дополнение к ответам выше можно сказать:

Мокрый - применяется там, где был процесс намокания, т. е. мокрое - не нормальное, а приобретенное состояние объекта. Например мокрая обувь, мокрое белье, еще говорят мокнуть под дождем, мокрый пол.

Сырой - состояние объекта (не приобретенное, а естественное) или процесс, но очень медленный: сырая древесина, сырая говядина, на улице сыро. Или второй вариант - отсыреть (долго находиться под воздействием влаги и потерять полезные свойства)

Answer (score 3):

Эти слова передают степень влажности - со словом мокрый можно сопоставить степень "полностью", а со словом сырой - "слегка".

Answer (score 3):

When meaning "damp", "wet", these words differ slightly.

To describe an object wet due to being covered with water, you can only use *мокрый*: *мокрая кошка*, *мокрый пол*. *Сырой* cannot be used here.

To describe an object moist because of containing water, you can use both words: *сырой песок* (or *мокрый песок*), *сырой луг* (or *мокрый луг*), *сырое утро* (or *мокрое утро*). *Сырой пол* does not mean a floor which had just been washed, but rather a floor permanently wet (because of a leak or something).

When meaning "raw", "uncooked", "not ready", only *сырой* can be used: *сырое мясо*, *сырая картошка*.

Answer (score 3):

'Сырая вода' means 'not boiled', got from open water, and its drinking can cause illness.
'Сырое мясо' also means 'not prepared'

Comment: While probably being legit, your answer does not seem to add to the answers given by the other users. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is our way of saying "thank you, I like this answer, I agree with it". Duplicate answers [will be removed](http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Answer (score 2):

Слово "мокрый" обычно употребляют, чтобы показать, что поверхность объекта покрыта водой, например: "мокрый пол" = "wet floor". Иногда мокрым называют то, что пропитано водой, например, "мокрое полотенце" = "wet towel".

Слово "сырой" могут употреблять в сходном значении. Например, "сырой пол" = "мокрый пол" = "wet floor". Еще "сырой" говорят, когда хотят обозначить повышенную влажность в течение длительного времени. Например, "сырой климат" или "сырой подвал".

"Сырая стена" скорее скажут, если это стена, пропитанная водой. Например, в затопленном подвале. "Мокрая стена" скажут про стену, которую только что забрызгали водой. Например, в ванной комнате.

Чаще слово "сырой" говорят, чтобы обозначить недостаточную готовность продукта. "Сырое мясо" = "raw meat". "Сырой пирог" = "undercooked pie". "Сырая вода" = "water which has not been boiled".

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Please don't repeat existing answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is our way of saying "thank you, I like this answer, I agree with it".

Answer (score 1):

Сырой can be used in 3 different cases:
1. related to wetness of thing - на улице сыро, сырое белье после стирки - in this case it less wet that мокрый.
2. as derivative from сырье - сырое мясо, сырая нефть.
3. relatively to cooking as measure of readiness.

And сырое мясо и сырой пирог very different usage of word сырой. Your can use ЕЩЕ сырое мясо with meaning of сырой пирог but only for meat in process of cooking.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between сырой пирог and сырое мясо better? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

здесь нужно ещё учитывать аспект времени, мокрым что то может быть сейчас, а сырым продолжительное время, например: сырая комната или сырой (скорее прохладный) или влажный (скорее тёплый)климат

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Answer (score -2):

дождь мокрый - степень влажности. хотя так говорить нельзя, но можно объяснить понятие влажности предмета.
Аналогично - туман сырой.
Но у слова "сырой" двойственное значение, его можно применять не только к пониманию определения степени влажности, но также к степени термической обработки какого либо продукта.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.